# Spring cache for a given request

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I am writing a web application using Spring MVC. I have a interface that looks like this:

```
public interface SubscriptionService
{
    public String getSubscriptionIDForUSer(String userID);
}
```

The `getSubscriptionIDForUser` actually makes a network call to another service to get the subscription details of the user. My business logic calls this method in multiple places in its logic. Hence, for a given HTTP request I might have multiple calls made to this method. So, I want to cache this result so that repeated network calls are not made for the same request. I looked at the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), but could not find references to how can I cache this result for the same request. Needless to say the cache should be considered invalid if it is a new request for the same `userID`.

My requirements are as follows:

1. For one HTTP request, if multiple calls are made to `getSubscriptionIDForUser`, the actual method should be executed only once. For all other invocations, the cached result should be returned.
2. For a different HTTP request, we should make a new call and disregard the cache hit, if at all, even if the method parameters are exactly the same.
3. The business logic might execute its logic in parallel from different threads. Thus for the same HTTP request, there is a possibility that Thread-1 is currently making the `getSubscriptionIDForUser` method call, and before the method returns, Thread-2 also tries to invoke the same method with the same parameters. If so, then Thread-2 should be made to wait for the return of the call made from Thread-1 instead of making another call. Once the method invoked from Thread-1 returns, Thread-2 should get the same return value.

Any pointers?

Update: My webapp will be deployed to multiple hosts behind a VIP. My most important requirement is Request level caching. Since each request will be served by a single host, I need to cache the result of the service call in that host only. A new request with the same userID must not take the value from the cache. I have looked through the docs but could not find references as to how it is done. May be I am looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EHCache](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://ehcache.org/&ei=O8sSUf6NCMXN0AGR-4CoAw&usg=AFQjCNG3eekIkqCShwGjcMl-cbjiR45wdg&sig2=JFt2XFN7HEqx63V9K-M6-g&bvm=bv.41934586,d.dmQ) comes to mind right off the bat, or you could even roll-your-own solution to cache the results in the service layer.  There are probably a billion options on caching here.  The choice depends on several factors, like do you need the values to timeout, or are you going to clean the cache manually.  Do you need a distributed cache, like in the case where you have a stateless REST application that is distributed amongst several app servers.  You you need something robust that can survive a crash or reboot.

Comment: My webapp will be deployed to multiple hosts behind a VIP. My most important requirement is Request level caching. Since each request will be served by a single host, I need to cache the result of the service call in that host only. A new request with the same userID must not take the value from the cache. I have looked through the docs but could not find references as to how it is done. May be I am   looking at the wrong place?

Comment: @SwarangaSarma what solution you finally used? I doubt if ehCache provides request scope based caching.

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to propose another solution that a bit smaller than one proposed by @Dmitry. Instead of implementing own `CacheManager` we can use `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` provided by Spring in 'spring-context' artifact. So, the code will look like this (configuration):

```
//add this code to any configuration class
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
}
```

and may be used:

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "cacheManager", cacheNames = "default")
public SomeCachedObject getCachedObject() {
    return new SomeCachedObject();
}
```

Comment: `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` should also work as the proxy mode, given that the callers are unlikely to be using anything particular to the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` class that's not on the `CacheManager` interface.

Comment: Although I am testing it more, but this solution seemed to have worked for me. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 7):

I ended up with solution as suggested by herman in his comment:

Cache manager class with simple HashMap:

```
public class RequestScopedCacheManager implements CacheManager {
 
    private final Map<String, Cache> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public RequestScopedCacheManager() {
        System.out.println("Create");
    }

    @Override
    public Cache getCache(String name) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(name, this::createCache);
    }
 
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    protected Cache createCache(String name) {
        return new ConcurrentMapCache(name);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Collection<String> getCacheNames() {
        return cache.keySet();
    }
 
    public void clearCaches() {
        cache.clear();
    }
 
}
```

Then make it RequestScoped:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public CacheManager requestScopedCacheManager() {
    return new RequestScopedCacheManager();
}
```

Usage:

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "requestScopedCacheManager", cacheNames = "default")
public YourCachedObject getCachedObject(Integer id) {
    //Your code
    return yourCachedObject;
}
```

**Update:**

After a while, I have found that my previous solution was incompatible with Spring-actuator. CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration is trying to initialize request scoped cache outside the request scope, which leads to exception.

Here is my alternative Implementation:

```
public class RequestScopedCacheManager implements CacheManager {


public RequestScopedCacheManager() {
}

@Override
public Cache getCache(String name) {
    Map<String, Cache> cacheMap = getCacheMap();
    return cacheMap.computeIfAbsent(name, this::createCache);
}

protected Map<String, Cache> getCacheMap() {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes == null) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Cache> cacheMap = (Map<String, Cache>) requestAttributes.getAttribute(getCacheMapAttributeName(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    if (cacheMap == null) {
        cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
        requestAttributes.setAttribute(getCacheMapAttributeName(), cacheMap, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    }
    return cacheMap;
}

protected String getCacheMapAttributeName() {
    return this.getClass().getName();
}

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
protected Cache createCache(String name) {
    return new ConcurrentMapCache(name);
}

@Override
public Collection<String> getCacheNames() {
    Map<String, Cache> cacheMap = getCacheMap();
    return cacheMap.keySet();
}

public void clearCaches() {
    for (Cache cache : getCacheMap().values()) {
        cache.clear();
    }
    getCacheMap().clear();
}
```

}

Then register a not(!) request scoped bean. Cache implementation will get request scope internally.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager requestScopedCacheManager() {
    return new RequestScopedCacheManager();
}
```

Usage:

```
    @Cacheable(cacheManager = "requestScopedCacheManager", cacheNames = "default")
public YourCachedObject getCachedObject(Integer id) {
    //Your code
    return yourCachedObject;
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. it's unfortunately not as elegant as @nndru syntax. Nevertheless, it's the only solution working with CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration. By the way, why CacheMetrics is not able to find the cacheManager bean ? That bean is supposed to be here and proxied by spring thanks to the `@Scope` annotation... Maybe web/mvc or anything is not yet initialize at that moment ?

Comment: The problem is, that Spring is trying to initialize the cache manager on container start. Trere is no request context at this point and spring throws an exception.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry. Thanks for the tips about actuator. Wouldn't have guessed this trouble before falling over it. By the way, why do you mention in your updated version to not(!) register the bean whereas you'r still using `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` annotation as in the previous version ? I guess you've forgot to adapt the code, but can't tell the right way to implement it in that case. A regular @Bean would be enought here ?

Comment: Hi @Lemmy. You are right. I forgot to remove Scope annotation. I've corrected my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work work of cache of Distributed application infrastructure as well? How does one configure Cache Clear functionality using EhCache? Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, would your updated solution require to run clearCaches() at some point? Do you need to issue "clears" on each request? Would this be an issue with multiple concurrent requests? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Laurentius, there is no need to call any "clears". Request scope will be cleaned automatically by Spring. Multiple requests are not an issue, because RequestContextHolder uses ThreadLocal internally to manage multiple threads. This solution is actually tested and used in production.

Comment: @SwapnilJaju Spring works with distributed caches out of the box.  You clear the cache with `@CacheEvict`.  This question is about short lived request level caching.  You don't need or want a distributed cache for request level caching.

Comment: if you don't need the CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration, you can also exclude it using:
`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration::class] )` and still use the `@RequestScope` cacheManager

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Cache annotations and create your own CacheManager that caches at request scope. Or you can use the one I wrote: https://github.com/rinoto/spring-request-cache

Comment: Your README.md has a warning to clear the cache each request.  Isn't it possible to simply make the CacheManager bean itself request scoped so each request will get a new instance?  I'm not even sure you'd need to write a custom implementation in that case.  After all you're storing the objects in a `ThreadLocal`, which is exactly what request scope does.