# Perform caching per request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My SpringBoot Rest Service makes an external webservice call to get a boolean value based on which subsequent events in the flow are performed. I make this call multiple times per request. However I want this call to be performed only one time per request. If I use @Cacheable annotation , it gets cached for subsequent requests as well. Is there a way to use Cacheable per request or any other mechanism in Spring to Cache the value in memory per request?

This is now resolved. I used the below -

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: Related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737553/spring-cache-for-a-given-request

Comment: Thanks @SheetalMohanSharma. I set the scope to "Request" instead and I was able to achieve what I was requesting

Comment: @PunterVicky please, write an answer about `SCOPE_REQUEST` and mark it as right answer.

Comment: Sure @AleksandrSemyannikov